# Print different language string with the English alphabet without translating it using Bash shell

Tags: bash, command-line

So, let's say I have a string in another language that uses a different character set, but I want to print that string in the English alphabet while only translating the characters in the string and not the word/phrase into English. Here are some examples of input and expected output (based on Google Translate where the translated string is "Hello")

| Language | Input | Output (Expected) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English | Hello | Hello |
| Spanish | Hola | Hola |
| Japanese | こんにちは | Kon'nichiwa |
| Russian | Привет | Privet |
| Korean | 안녕하세요 | annyeonghaseyo |

While I do know I can translate with `translate-shell` or `deepl`, I'm not sure if either command can do this. Is there any way to do this with either command, or is there another command for it?

Comment: While I think that for Japanese, Russian and Korean there's somewhat standardized ways of transliteration, this might be a bit hard in general, because how you "spell" a word in latin script depends on how you pronounce it, and it'll not come to a surprise to you as speaker of multiple western European languages that this pronounciation can sometimes depend on which meaning of a word is meant.

Comment: But you can have tools like `espeak-ng --ipa -v jpx/ja こんにちは` try and emit international phonetic alphabet. That, by the way, already illustrates how hard that is. `は` is a `ha` sound, when written alone. But in this context, it should clearly be pronounced `wa` :) welcome to the complicated, sometimes nonsystematic world of human languages.